# Como dar espaçamento (distancia) bottom em uma li

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Olá, pessoal. Sou novo com desenvolvimento e estou estudando um pouco de front-end (e adorando hehe)

Estou, para fins estudantis, criando um site simples de uma loja. Criei um menu no topo dessa página, onde tenho uma nav com uma div que suporta minha ul com as li's que representam as opções de navegação do site nesse menu(header).

Fiz as opções com ul li, porém elas ficam no final do menu, e eu gostaria de aproximá-las um pouco mais da minha logo, que fica um pouco acima delas, ambos centralizados no menu.

Procurei bastante e não achei nada que me ajudasse, ou se achei não soube aplicar.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnvy36rz/)

```css
.cabecalho {
    background-color: #ffd22a;
    margin: 9px;
}

#li-princ {
    text-align: center;
}
.img-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; 
    bottom: 60px; 
}

.cabecalho nav h1 img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
.menu-princ {
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    
}

.opcoes-princ {
}

.cabecalho nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 10%;

}

.mainbg {
    background-image: url("../img/bgnova2.jpg");
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecalho">
    <nav class="menu-princ">
        <h1><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo da Loja Fake" class="img-container"></h1>

        <div id="li-princ">
            <ul class="opcoes-princ">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Conheça</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mídias Sociais</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            

    </nav>
</div>


</header>

<main class="mainbg">
</main>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Eu já tentei, de diversas formas, fazer isso. A princípio pensei que seria só dar um bottom: *n* px no "opcoes-princ".

Alguém aí consegue me ajudar? Faltou alguma coisa? Se tiverem dicas de material de estudo, ou artigos interessantes, por favor, sintam-se a vontade para me indicar!

Comment: Seria interessante vc incluir uma imagem na sua pergunta mostrando como mais extamente vc quer que fique o layout final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá

Para fazer o teste coloquei uma imagem de exemplo no seu logo.

Para aproximar o menu do logo é só alterar no seu css, no 
.menu-princ
você pode diminuir o padding-top e adicionar um padding-bottom.

Para aproximar mais ainda, você deve remover o 
bottom: 60px;
de .img-container

```css
.cabecalho {
    background-color: #ffd22a;
    margin: 9px;
}

#li-princ {
    text-align: center;
}

.img-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}

.cabecalho nav h1 img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}

.menu-princ {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.opcoes-princ {
}

.cabecalho nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 10%;

}

.mainbg {
    background-image: url("../img/bgnova2.jpg");
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cabecalho">

    <nav class="menu-princ">
        <h1><img src="http://digitaltroop.com.br/clientes/dressart/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/SampleLogo-820x421.png" alt="Logo da Loja Fake" class="img-container"></h1>
        <div id="li-princ">
            <ul class="opcoes-princ">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Conheça</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mídias Sociais</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            

    </nav>
</div>


</header>

<main class="mainbg">
</main>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria fazer. Peço desculpas a todos pela falta de clareza no que passei e agradeço imensamente a todos os amigos que participaram. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo disse o erro está aqui nesta parte:

```
.img-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; 
    bottom: 60px; 
}
```

retire o `bottom: 60px;`:

```
.img-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;  
}
```